# Ember: set value of property on text field

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have two inputs, one for a number of miles and the other for a number of kilometers. I'm using a keyup event in each input to trigger a calculation in the other input. So, if I type 5 in the kilometers input, the value of the miles input will automatically update to 3.1068.

The miles input is bound to a `miles` property on a model, but the programmatic update of the miles field doesn't trigger the bound property to update. How do I make this work?

(Also: I'm only interested in the value of the kilometers input for calculation and display purposes. It doesn't need to be a property.)

Here are the input views:

```
App.MilesInput = Ember.TextField.extend({
    elementId: 'miles-input',
    focusIn: function() {
        this.set('value', '');
    },
    keyUp: function() {
        var miles = $('#miles-input').val();

        $('#kilometers-input').val(miles * 1.609344);
    }
});

App.KilometersInput = Ember.TextField.extend({
    elementId: 'kilometers-input',
    focusIn: function() {
        this.set('value', '');
    },
    keyUp: function() {
        var kilometers = $('#kilometers-input').val();

        $('#miles-input').val(kilometers * 0.621371192);
    }
});
```

and their corresponding template elements:

```
<div>
    {{view App.MilesInput value=miles type="number"}}
    <label>Mi</label>

    {{view App.KilometersInput type="number"}}
    <label>K</label>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How did you go with this? Did you try the solution I provided? Is there any reason you did not approve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed property and assign the same computed property for

```
 App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   miles:'',
   kilometers: function(){
    return this.get('miles') *0.621371192;
  }.property('miles')
 });
```

In your template

```
   {{input value=miles}}
   {{input value=kilometers}}
```

As far as I know you dont need a custom viewElement for this.

I suggest you to read this
http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/

Here is a JSBin 
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kitus/1/

Tell me if this works for you

Comment: This is the exact solution that I used originally, but I need the calculation to work both ways—calculate miles when I enter kilometers and calculate kilometers when I enter miles. I tried using a two-way computed property, but it creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
 miles:'',
 kilometers:'',
  calcK: function (){
    this.set('kilometers',this.get('miles')*0.621371192)
  }.observes('miles'),
  calcM: function (){
 this.set('miles',this.get('kilometers')/0.621371192)
}.observes('kilometers')
 });
```

jsbin

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yopew/2/edit

Comment: I'd love it if this worked, but it doesn't. The calculation is circular. As you type in one of the fields, the value of the other property is trying to calculate the value that you're typing. Try putting "26.2" in the miles field and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to temporarily disable observers when there are mutually dependant properties in order to stop feedback loops.  There is precious little documentation on this but I have used this approach and it does work.

The code below disables and re-enables the opposite observer around the setting of the property:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  miles:'',
  kilometers:'',
  calcK: function (obj,key){
    Ember._suspendObserver(this, 'kilometers', null, 'calcM', function() {
      obj.set('kilometers', obj.get('miles')*0.621371192);
    });
  }.observes('miles'),
  calcM: function (obj,key){
    Ember._suspendObserver(this, 'miles', null, 'calcK', function() {
      obj.set('miles', obj.get('kilometers')/0.621371192)
    });
  }.observes('kilometers')
});
```

Since the above code avoids the feedback loop the input field the user is typing into wont get updated and their input won't get affected.

Here is a working JSBin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/boqos/1/

Comment: You're welcome, I just hope others dont have to go through the pain to find the secret sauce. If it works please approve my answer so others can find the answer easily too. It took me a fair amount of time working it out and trying various things that didn't work on my own project because there wasn't an example anywhere I could find that covered mutually dependant properties which can both be edited.